# jquery multiple append avoid increasing window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have been working on the next example, I'm adding html to a div, at some point the size of the window start increasing, is there a way to avoid this?

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/9rysbxw2/12/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#b').click(function() {
    $('#elDiv').append('<br><strong>Hello</strong><br>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>I would like to say: </p>
<button id="b">click now</button>
<div id="elDiv"></div>
```

Comment: What do you expect when you keep appending data? The content grows because there is more. What do you want to happen??

Answer (score 0):

I defined a style for the `elDiv` to be 100px `height` and scroll when content exceeds the div's height:

```
.myclass{
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9rysbxw2/18/

Answer (score 0):

to avoid this behavio i think you should set a size to the  element and define a overflow behavior. So the content that is been added to the div will stay inside it. here is a modification of you code sample:

```js
$('#b').click(function(){
    $( '#elDiv').append('<br><strong>Hello</strong><br>');
});
```

```html
<p>I would like to say: </p>
 <button id="b">click now
 </button>
<div id="elDiv" style="height:100px; overflow: auto;">
</div>
<!-- NOTICE THE OVERFLOW PROPERTIE I ADDED AND THE FIXED HEIGHT -->
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issue using the style properties

```
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
```

this way i can add multiple div at any position without increasing the screen size

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/9rysbxw2/25/)